# What does it mean to multiply structure members in this c++ code

Tags: c++, structure

I have a question concerning this code from Thinking in c++ book , this is a tiny c style library for learning the process of memory allocation , what does it mean to write

```
int startBytes = s->next * s->size;
```

in this code , what does this multiplication mean ?

```
//: C04:CLib.h
// Header file for a C-like library
// An array-like entity created at runtime
typedef struct CStashTag {
    int size;
    // Size of each space
    int quantity; // Number of storage spaces
    int next;
    // Next empty space
    // Dynamically allocated array of bytes:
    unsigned char* storage;
} CStash;

void initialize(CStash* s, int size);
void cleanup(CStash* s);
int add(CStash* s, const void* element);
void* fetch(CStash* s, int index);
int count(CStash* s);
void inflate(CStash* s, int increase);
///:~



//: C04:CLib.cpp {O}
// Implementation of example C-like library
// Declare structure and functions:
#include "CLib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

/ Quantity of elements to add
// when increasing storage:
const int increment = 100;

void initialize(CStash* s, int sz) {
    s->size = sz;
    s->quantity = 0;
    s->storage = 0;
    s->next = 0;
}

int add(CStash* s, const void* element) {
    if(s->next >= s->quantity) //Enough space left?
    inflate(s, increment);
    // Copy element into storage,
    // starting at next empty space:
    int startBytes = s->next * s->size;
    unsigned char* e = (unsigned char*)element;
    for(int i = 0; i < s->size; i++)
        s->storage[startBytes + i] = e[i];
        s->next++;
        return(s->next - 1); // Index number
    }
    void* fetch(CStash* s, int index) {
    // Check index boundaries:
    assert(0 <= index);
    if(index >= s->next)
        return 0; // To indicate the end

    // Produce pointer to desired element:
    return &(s->storage[index * s->size]);
}

int count(CStash* s) {
    return s->next; // Elements in CStash
}

void inflate(CStash* s, int increase) {
    assert(increase > 0);
    int newQuantity = s->quantity + increase;
    int newBytes = newQuantity * s->size;
    int oldBytes = s->quantity * s->size;
    unsigned char* b = new unsigned char[newBytes];
    for(int i = 0; i < oldBytes; i++)
        b[i] = s->storage[i]; // Copy old to new

    delete [](s->storage); // Old storage
    s->storage = b; // Point to new memory
    s->quantity = newQuantity;
}

void cleanup(CStash* s) {
    if(s->storage != 0) {
        cout << "freeing storage" << endl;
        delete []s->storage;
    }
} ///:~



//: C04:CLibTest.cpp
//{L} CLib
// Test the C-like library
#include "CLib.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  // Define variables at the beginning
  // of the block, as in C:
  CStash intStash, stringStash;
  int i;
  char* cp;
  ifstream in;
  string line;
  const int bufsize = 80;
  // Now remember to initialize the variables:
  initialize(&intStash, sizeof(int));
  for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  add(&intStash, &i);
  for(i = 0; i < count(&intStash); i++)
  cout << "fetch(&intStash, " << i << ") = "
  << *(int*)fetch(&intStash, i)
  << endl;
  // Holds 80-character strings:
  initialize(&stringStash, sizeof(char)*bufsize);
  in.open("CLibTest.cpp");
  assert(in);
  while(getline(in, line))
  add(&stringStash, line.c_str());
  i = 0;
  while((cp = (char*)fetch(&stringStash,i++))!=0)
  cout << "fetch(&stringStash, " << i << ") = "
  << cp << endl;
  cleanup(&intStash);
  cleanup(&stringStash);
} ///:~
```

Comment: Please indent your code !

Comment: Thinking in C++ by writing C-style code? Sounds like a problem waiting to happen.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's getting the next free location by multiplying the size of the object by the index number of the next available space. So if the next space is 10, and the object size is 10, it will start allocating at byte index 100.

Comment: Thank you for Answering my question. In the implementation of this book example initialize function was called like: 'code' intitialize(&intStash,sizeof(int)) 'code' , this function assigns 0 to next , then add function was called for intStash , so what is the aim of saying 'code' int startBytes = s->next*s->size 'code' should the direct result be 0 for startBytes variable as well?. I edited the post to include the full example. –  user3270926 6 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

It is a straight multiplication of the values of `next` and `size`, I'm going to guess it's calculating an offset somewhere. From looking at the code, `size` is set by the `sz` parameter of the initialize function.

Comment: I made an edit , can you see the full code ; it may clarify my old question.